# Seeking high resolution transportation map of North Carolina?

Tags: usa, geospatial, transportation

I am trying to find a transportation map of North Carolina with geolocation to overlay into my project.

I have gone in circles on the USGS sites and other sources.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think this question would be suitable for researching/asking on the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: agreed, can it be moved?

Comment: By "geolocation" do you mean Linear Referencing System (LRS)? Did you see this: https://connect.ncdot.gov/resources/gis/Pages/GIS-Data-Layers.aspx  ?

Comment: Could you be more specific by what you mean by "transportation map [...] with geolocation"?

Comment: A road map. I guess I could have just said that, but the closest i'v gotten to finding what I need was categorized as a transportation map.

Comment: Would OpenStreetMap meet your requirement?  What data are you looking for on this map?

Answer (score 3):

[North Carolina DOT GIS Data Layers](https://connect.ncdot.gov/resources/gis/Pages/GIS-Data-Layers.aspx)  are what you want.